# What is the easiest way to "run an instance in a separate Thread"?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

I am trying to simulate a distributed algorithm by putting each process (class) to a separate Thread, so they will act as a real isolated processes. The processes should be able to communicate between each other.

What I am trying to do can be demonstrated by this piece of code:

```
public class Process
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Run called from thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    public void Fnc()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fnc called from thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main is running in thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        Process p1 = new Process();

        var t1 = new Thread(p1.Run);
        t1.Start();


        // This should call Fnc() in t1 Thread. It should also return immediatelly not waiting for method Fnc() to finish.
        p1.Fnc();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I am getting this output:

```
Main is running in thread 9
Run called from thread 10
Fnc called from thread 9
```

I want to get something like this:

```
Main is running in thread 9
Run called from thread 10
Fnc called from thread 10
```

Is it possible to achieve this kind of functionality?

Thank you!

Comment: When you want to isolate processes, you should use processes instead of threads. Threads do not act like real isolated processes.

Comment: The first output is obvious as you are invoking p1.fun() from main thread. Its not clear to us as what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Should `Run` and `Fnc` run simultaneous? Then you will need more than one thread. Or should `Run` pause execution when starting `Fnc`? Or are both short running procs? Do you want to run them in a separate process or just in a separate thread?

Comment: @PVitt: Thank you. Is it possible to run processes easily from code and then pass messages to them just by calling their methods?

Comment: Process in the above example is just ordinary class. Are you confusing this process with .Net managed "Process"?

Comment: @Jan `Fnc` should wait until `Run` ends. All methods of one instance should be running in a one thread (or process?), so two of them can't run simultaneously.

Comment: @jakubka: No, that's not that easy. But please describe your problem. Processes seem to be part of a solution you think of. But for me it seems to be wrong. But I don't know your problem so it's hard to help.

Comment: @PawanMishra I am trying to "simulate" process. Maybe this is the wrong aproach and I should really user real processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Thread Parallel Library:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew( ( ) => p1.Run )
    .ContinueWith( ( t ) => p1.Fnc );
```

Or you create a small helper method:

```
class Program
{
    private static Process p1 = new Process();
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main is running in thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        var t1 = new Thread(Helper);
        t1.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static Helper( )
    {
        p.Run();
        p.Fnc();
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution with Tasks will do it! Thank you. Your second option (as well as @RedHat's solution) will work only in one simple case, but I need a more generic solution.

Answer (score 2):

As @PVitt says it's not reliable test of the programm you gonna to deliver. What you need is *real* separate processes.

Create an executable and run it with different command line parameters and/or after use any RPC available in .NET framework to make them "talk" with each other.

Answer (score 2):

There is no mechanism to select a specific thread to run a method unless that thread is explicitly designed to support this.  Essential ingredients for such a thread is a dispatch loop and a thread-safe queue to receive parcels of work.  Otherwise well covered in the literature as the [producer/consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem).  What you are asking for is otherwise simple to implement:

```
public void Run()
{
    Fnc();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Action action = () => { p.Run(); p.Fnc(); };
var t1 = new Thread(action);
t1.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use .Net 4, I'd suggest using Tasks (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx), it's really easy to manage/cancel them.

To run what you need just write:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{p.Run(); p.Fnc();});
```